# Where could I find some UML samples?

Tags: uml

I need a punch of samples of UML diagrams to get an start point to develop my own diagrams.

Does anyone know about a good website where I could find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The best resource for learning UML is Martin Fowler's ["UML Distilled"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687).  Now in its third edition, this thin gem has stood the test of time.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Agile Modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/) to be a good resource for samples, and +1 for UML Distilled.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a good bunch of described examples:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/using-the-uml-a-live-example-21114

by the way it would be useful to know which kind of UML diagrams are you interested in, just to narrow your search.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [google image search for UML](http://images.google.ca/images?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA348CA348&q=uml&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wi) ti would give you lots of examples of other peoples diagrams

wikipedia also has a good article on the [different types of UML diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)

Comment: For someone that is just learning, this isn't the best place to look. It does return results... however the results aren't noted as being correct or what they are trying to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like UML for design patterns a good place to look would be [Dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx). Also I found one by a [Etsi.org](http://portal.etsi.org/mbs/Languages/UML/uml_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This page on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) gives an overview of the different components of UML and how they are used...

Answer (score 0):

The Sparx web site as a [UML Tutorial](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/); see also [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/uml-tutorial.html) and [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/tutorial/uml_tutorial2.html).