# Simple UML project to practice coding from UML

Tags: uml

I would like to find a simple (read small project) fully developed UML project. My goal is to practice coding an application from a professional grade UML project and at the same time get some experience to start creating my own UML projects.

Ideally, the project would be a web app although I know, that in theory, UML should be platform independent, but I'm not close to platform specific (language, framework) projects has long as it is for software.

Thank you.

Comment: Found similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684407/where-could-i-find-some-uml-samples?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple starting point you could try [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/).

Once you have got to grips with the basics download the trial edition of [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/trial.html) and play around with the reverse engineering an open source project in the supported languages.

Comment: I will look it up over the week-end